# How to obtain proper React key for Marker component?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

When using [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) and rendering e.g. several Marker components from array of latlons, one ends up with e.g.:

```
latlons.map((lat, lon, i) => <Marker key={i} position={L.latLng(lat, lon)} />
```

however the `key={i}` is not a good practice as explained [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md).

It does not seems react-leaflet provides tools to generate some unique key for a component. In some cases one may use `key={lat.toString() + lon.toString()}`, however this approach will not work when the Marker should be draggable.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a unique string of your choosing.  If you're saving your markers to a database, a good option would be to create a string that includes the primary key value of your marker.  If you need to generate something on the fly you could use the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package to generate a unique id.